# Is there a syntax-checker for Octave similar to Matlab's mlint and checkcode?

Tags: syntax, octave

I would expect such a beast to have the same license as Octave itself.
I looked at the Octave option parser, and it looks like this ability
isn't in core Octave.

Answer (score 8):

No. It was still on the project's future feature list as of 09/23/12.

http://wiki.octave.org/Projects

The tenth item under 'Interpreter'.

Comment: The item is called "Add a command-line option to tell Octave to just do syntax checking and not execute statements."